# when I'm pressing Check which is"chckAns" button my app is suddenly kept crashing

Tags: java, android

think the problem lies on the class onClick but I'm not sure though. Whenever I check my answer on the game, it just suddenly crash

package com.example.machineproblemsix;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    static Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
    public void doBack(View v){
        finish();
    }
    public static class LoginDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
                AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jake_layout, null);
            final EditText etAnswer = (EditText)    
                    v.findViewById(R.id.answer);
            final EditText etAnswerTwo = (EditText)    
                    v.findViewById(R.id.answerTwo);
            builder.setView(v)
                   .setPositiveButton(R.string.login, new 
                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 
                            id) {
                           String answer, answertwo;
                          answer = etAnswer.getText().toString();
                          answertwo = etAnswerTwo.getText().toString();
                           String msg;
                           if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("jake")){
                               msg = "CORRECT!";
                           }else if(answertwo.equalsIgnoreCase("beemo")|| 
                           (answertwo.equalsIgnoreCase("bmo"))){
                               msg = "CORRECT!";
                           } else {
                               msg = "TRY AGAIN!";
                           }
                           Toast.makeText(context, msg,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                            int id) {
                           // User cancelled the dialog
                       }
                   });
            // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            return builder.create();
        }
}
    public void showLogin(View v){
         DialogFragment loginFragment = new LoginDialogFragment();
         loginFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "login");
}   
}
```

I think the problem lies on the class onClick but I'm not sure though. Whenever I check my answer on the game, it just suddenly crash

================================================================================

**Log:**

```
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924): Process: com.example.machineproblemsix, PID: 924
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.example.machineproblemsix.SecondActivity$LoginDialogFragment$1.onClick(SecondActivity.java:52)
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
02-07 23:30:29.070: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

================================================================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:background="#000"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
       android:scaleType="center"
       android:src="@drawable/jake" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_answer"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: without crash log (logcat) it is difficult to forecast the issue please paste your logcat as well

Comment: please pate your layout (jake_layout)

Comment: I'm sorry because my codes are not organize, I took some of it in my other activities just to speed things up

Comment: where is you method registered "showLogin" in XML with which view you have bind it ?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that as of 2016, eclipse is no longer supported as an android development environment. Also, the tag is unrelated to your question because it is not about eclipse

Answer (score 0):

According to Logcat, there is an error at Line No. 52. I can't know for sure (because there is no line no. included in code) but I believe that line is:

```
Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

There is only two variable in above line: context and msg.
Since you assign value in msg, which mean "context" is a problem. You forget to assign value in context which is the reason "NullPointerException" occur.

You should use "getActivity()" instead of using "static context" which will make line 52, look like this :

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Organize your code like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jake_layout, null);
        final EditText etAnswer = (EditText)    
                v.findViewById(R.id.answer);
        final EditText etAnswerTwo = (EditText)    
                v.findViewById(R.id.answerTwo);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
            AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setView(v)
.setPositiveButton(R.string.login, new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
String answer, answertwo;
answer = etAnswer.getText().toString();
answertwo = etAnswerTwo.getText().toString();
String msg;
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("jake")){
   msg = "CORRECT!";
   }else if(answertwo.equalsIgnoreCase("beemo")|| 
                       (answertwo.equalsIgnoreCase("bmo"))){
                           msg = "CORRECT!";
                       } else {
                           msg = "TRY AGAIN!";
                       }
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                        int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
```